# How to test my own data Types using HUnit in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hunit

Part of Queue.hs:

```
module Queue ( Queue, emptyQueue, isEmptyQueue, enQueue, deQueue ) where

data Queue a = EmptyQueue | Single a | Q a ( Queue a ) a deriving (Show, Eq)

emptyQueue :: Queue a
emptyQueue = EmptyQueue

enQueue :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
enQueue x EmptyQueue = Single x
enQueue x (Single q) = Q q (EmptyQueue) x
enQueue x (Q qf q qb) = Q qf (enQueue qb q) x
```

I was using print, see if them correct one by one.
Now I want to test them using HUint.

Main.hs:

```
module Main where
import Queue 
import Test.HUnit

test1 = TestCase $ assertEqual "" (Single 'a'::Queue Char) $ enQueue 'a' emptyQueue
tests = TestList [TestLabel "test1" test1]

main = do runTestTT tests
```

Here's what I got:

```
*Queue> :r
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )

Main.hs:5:36: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Single’
Failed, modules loaded: Queue.
```

So how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you exporting the `Queue` type from `Queue.hs`?  If you have `module Queue (Queue) where ...` it wouldn't be exporting the constructors, you'd need `module Queue (Queue(..)) where` to export all constructors of the `Queue` type.

Comment: @bheklilr I've edit questions.

Comment: The error still isn't fixed. Add ``(..)`` to the second Queue in Queue.hs

Comment: To complete the other two comments: 
`module Queue ( Queue(..), …)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `Queue` datatype should be abstract and opaque, so exposing all constructors is not a good idea. However, you can split your implementation into two submodules:

```
module Queue.Internal where --expose all internal stuff

data Queue = <...>


module Queue (Queue, emptyQueue, <...>) where --expose user API only

import Queue.Internal


module Queue.Tests where

import Queue.Internal --to get access to „guts“

test = <...>


module Main where

import Queue --to just use the type
```

Some library types (like `ByteString`s) are made this way.

Comment: The file Queue.hs is assignment,  only can add implementation below it. Seems ByteString is a good idea, I've tried it, but how could I convert  the result of (enQueue 'a' emptyQueue) to ByteString?

Comment: @liubiantao I meant not to use ByteString, but to check how it is organized internally. Well, if you have only a single module, you have to export all `Queue` constructors (as it was already suggested) or write tests in the Queue module and export a test suit.